# How to concat arguments to an existing Dockerfile CMD?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-command

Suppose we have a Dockerfile with some CMD and we produced and image from it. Now suppose that we write a docker-compose and one of the services is built from that image.

What I want to do is running the same command but concatenating my own new parameters.

As an example, suppose the original CMD is

`java -jar app.jar --argumentA=valA`

I want the command to be

`java -jar app.jar --argumentA=valA --argumentB=valB`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you would want to accomplish, but...

Dockerfile exposes both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` for being able to execute commands. These also can be used in conjunction, but in this case the `ENTRYPOINT` will be the command what we want to execute and the `CMD` will represent some default arguments for the `ENTRYPOINT` ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)).

For example:

```
FROM openjdk:11

COPY . /target/app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar", "--argumentA=valA"]

CMD ["--argumentB=valB"]
```

The `--argumentB=valB` will be appended to the `java -jar app.jar --argumentA=valA`, if we run the image like this:

```
docker build -t app .
docker run app # # the command executed will be java -jar app.jar --argumentA=valA --argumentB=valB
```

But the `CMD` part will be overridden if we provide other arguments when we run the docker image:

```
docker build -t app .
docker run app --argumentA=valC # the command executed will be java -jar app.jar --argumentA=valA --argumentB=valC
```

Also, we can commit the `CMD` and have the `ENTRYPOINT` only, if we don't require some defaults to be appended to the `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You made it super clear